# Is it possible to have a namespace for a cluster of classes in Salesforce

Tags: package, namespace

I searched for namespace and package in Salesforce but did not find a way to use a namespace to package a cluster of classes without affecting others. Consequently, if we have a big project and wants to put classes under two different namespaces the only way to do that is creating two managed packages which seems bad to me.

Is there a possible way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Namespaces" are salesforce's version of code isolation for ISVs so their code and objects (database objects) won't clash with a client's code and objects (and other ISVs). "Packages" are a convenient way to distribute code and objects, but doesn't offer any specific isolation, except for managed packages.

You can, however, use limited "packaging" within a class (inner classes) to achieve a similar effect. It's not as convenient as in Java, because such classes can only be one level deep, and you can't "import" them to save typing. Also, some features, like the Database.Batchable interface, don't work on inner classes.

For example, you might write the following class:

```
public class Common {
    public class TypeA {
    // some stuff here
    }
    public class TypeB {
    // Some stuff here
    }
}
```

You can then refer to TypeA and TypeB through Common:

```
Common.TypeA varA = new Common.TypeA();
Common.TypeB varB = new Common.TypeB();
```

Perhaps in the future, there might be a way to have packages, but for now, the best you can do is [vote on this Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bp88AAC).